# How do I evaluate the following definite integral: $\int^1_0\frac{x^2\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int^1_0\frac{x^2\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$
I tried using by parts but it didn't help. Also none of the properties of definite integral helps.

Comment: it should be $\pi /8-1/4\,\pi \,\ln  \left( 2 \right) $

Comment: right, will you please provide me a hint ?

Comment: Have you tried a trigonometric substitution? In general, when you see anything of the form $\sqrt{a^{2}\pm x^{2}}$, you want to apply a trigonometric substitution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $x=\sin y$

$$I=\int_0^1\dfrac{x^2\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2y\ln(\sin y)dy$$

$$2I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin y)dy-\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos2y\ln(\sin y)dy$$

For the first half, see [How do you evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(\sin x) dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453249/how-do-you-evaluate-the-integral-int-0-frac-pi2-log-sin-x-dx)

For the second,

$$\int\cos2y\ln(\sin y)dy=\ln(\sin y)\int\cos2y\ dy-\int\left(\dfrac{d\ \ln(\sin y)}{dy}\int\cos2y\ dy\right)dy=?$$

Hope you can take it from here!

Answer (score 6):

Let $~I(k)=\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{x^k}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}~dx.~$ Then our integral becomes $I'(2).~$ At the same time, a simple

trigonometric substitution yields $~I(k)=\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sin^kx~dx.~$ But the latter is nothing more than

the famous [Wallis integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals), whose relation to the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) is well-known. We do not need

to go through the former to show a link to the latter. Indeed, a simple substitution of the form

$t=x^2$ would have sufficed to establish such a connection. We have $I(k)=\dfrac\pi{k~B\bigg(\dfrac12~,~\dfrac k2\bigg)}$ .

Differentiating with regard to *k*, and using the relation between the beta and [$\Gamma$ functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), we

will inevitably have to employ [digamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), which are nothing more than [harmonic 

 numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) in disguise. In particular, [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) for extending the latter to non-natural

arguments will be of great help in evaluating $\psi_0\bigg(\dfrac32\bigg).~$ The final result should be

> $$I'(2)~=~\dfrac\pi8\bigg(1-2\ln2\bigg).$$

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite the integral as$$I(a)=\lim\limits_{a\to0}\frac {\partial}{\partial a}\int\limits_0^1dx\,\frac {x^{a+2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$And make the substitution $u=x^2$. You should get the resulting integral in terms of the beta function.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^1 \frac{x^2\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx \\
&= - \int_0^1 \left[\int_x^1 \frac{dy}y\right] \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx \tag1 \\
&= - \int_0^1 \left[\int_0^y \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx\right] \frac{dy}y \tag2 \\
&= \frac12 \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-y^2} \, dy + \int_0^1 \left(\arctan\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-y^2}}y\right) - \frac\pi2\right)\,\frac{dy}y \\
&= \frac\pi8 + \int_1^\infty \left(\frac\pi2-\arctan(z)\right)\,\frac{1+z^2}{2z} \cdot 2\frac{1-z^2}{(1+z^2)^2} \, dz \tag3 \\
&= \frac\pi8 + \int_1^\infty \arctan\left(\frac1z\right) \cdot \frac{1-z^2}{z(1+z^2)} \, dz \tag4 \\
&= \frac\pi8 - \int_0^1 \arctan(w) \cdot \frac{1-w^2}{w(1+w^2)} \, dw \tag5 \\
&= \frac\pi8 + \frac\pi4\ln(2) + \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(w) - \ln(1+w^2)}{1+w^2} \, dw \\
&= \boxed{\frac\pi8 - \frac\pi4\ln(2)}
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ : integral definition of $\ln(x)$
- $(2)$ : apply Fubini's theorem
- $(3)$ : substitute $z=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1-y^2}}y \iff y=\dfrac{2z}{1+z^2}$
- $(4)$ : recall $\arctan(z)+\arctan\left(\dfrac1z\right)=\dfrac\pi2$ for $z>0$
- $(5)$ : substitute $w=\dfrac1z$
- $(6)$ : integrate by parts

Evaluation of the remaining integrals can be done using the results from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/817047/170231) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3148275/170231).

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts: IBP.
$\begin{align}\require{enclose}
\int_0^1\frac{x^2\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx&\stackrel{IBP}=\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{\left.\left(\frac12\arcsin x-\frac12x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\ln x\right\rvert_0^1}-\int_0^1\left(\frac12\frac{\arcsin x}x-\frac12\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)dx\\
&=\frac\pi 8-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\arcsin x}xdx\\
&\stackrel{IBP}=\frac\pi 8+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\\
&\stackrel{x\rightarrow\sin x}=\frac\pi 8+\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\sin x\,dx\\
&=\frac\pi 8-\frac\pi 4\ln2.
\end{align}$