# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln (x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln (x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\;,$ Put $x=\cos \phi\;,$ Then $dx = -\sin \phi d\phi$

and Changing Limit, We get

$$\displaystyle I = -\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0}\cos \phi \cdot \ln(\cos \phi )d\phi = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos \phi)\cdot \cos \phi d\phi$$

Now Using Integration by parts, We get

$$\displaystyle I = \left[\ln(\cos \phi)\cdot \sin \phi\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2 \phi}{\cos \phi}d\phi$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \left[\ln(\cos \phi)\cdot \sin \phi\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(1-\cos^2 \phi)}{\cos \phi}d\phi$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \left[\ln(\cos \phi)\cdot \sin \phi\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sec \phi d\phi-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos \phi d\phi$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \left[\ln(\cos \phi)\cdot \sin \phi\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\left[\ln\left|\sec \phi+\tan \phi\right|\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-\left[\sin \phi\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \left[\ln(\cos \phi)\cdot \sin \phi\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\left[\ln\left|\sec \phi+\tan \phi\right|\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-1$$

Now How can I solve after that, Help Required, Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It looks like you already solved it?

Comment: actually here How can I put that upper and lower limit. means in first part, $\ln(0)\cdot 1 = -\infty$ and in second part $\ln|\frac{2}{0}|$

Comment: I think that you have a problem in the formula just after " integrating by parts We get": The integrated part does not exist (infinite limit if $\phi \to \pi/2$ ) and the integral neither (problem at $\pi/2$). To correct choose $\sin(\phi)-1$ as a primitive for $\cos(\phi)$. Then the integrated part is $0$, and your integral is convergent.

Comment: @Kelenner ...Nice spot! Integration by parts can be quiet subtle

Comment: A very [similar](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538682) question.

Comment: I think I would have integrated by parts instead.

Comment: The integral screams for the substitution $u^{2}=x$. Then you just have som derivative of a beta-function, which is easy to handle when you know its relationship to the Gamma-function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An alternative:

Consider

$$
J(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^a(\phi)d\phi
$$

differentiating w.r.t $a$ gives us
$$
\partial_a J(a)\big|_{a=1}=-I
$$

But on the other hand $J(a)$ is just a [Wallis integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) and therefore

$$
I=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\partial_a\left( \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{a}{2}+1\right)}\right)\big|_{a=1}
$$

which yields the desiered result after using a [special value of the Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)

$$
I=\log(2)-1
$$

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $t^2=1-x^2$

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln (x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
&=\frac12 \int_0^1 \ln(1-t^2)d(t-1)\\
&\overset{ibp} =-\int_0^1\frac t{1+t}dt
=\ln2-1
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^1 \frac{x \ln (x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \left[- \int_x^1 \frac{dy}{y} \right] \frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx \\
&= - \int_0^1 \left[\int_0^y \frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx\right] \, \frac{dy}y \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2} - 1}y \, dy \\
&= \ln(2)-1
\end{align*}$$